# Using enums and switch instead of visitor pattern

Tags: c++, enums, visitor-pattern

I've got a tree that represents a mathematical expression, and I thought in order to calculate the value of an expression tree, I would implement the visitor pattern, however in C++ this involves a lot of repeating yourself, as the methods to accept a visitor have to be on every subclass, because even though the methods are identical, the types are not.

```
class Node {
  virtual void Acccept(Visitor *visitor) = 0;
};
class ConstantNode : Node {
  virtual void Accept(Visitor *visitor) {
    visitor->visit( this );
  }
};

class VariableNode : Node {
  virtual void Accept( Visitor *visitor) {
    visitor->visit( this );
  }
};

class Visitor {
  virtual void visit(ConstantNode *node) = 0;
  virtual void visit(VariableNode *node) = 0;
};
class CalculateVisitor : Visitor {
  virtual void visit(ConstantNode *node) { /* code */ }
  virtual void visit(VariableNode *node) { /* code */ }
};
```

This also has the problem that because the methods are virtual, you can't have templates nodes.

It just seems a lot easier to have an enum, where's there's one case for each Node and you just switch on the enum in a method instead of the visitor pattern.

```
class Node {
  enum NodeType {
    Constant,
    Variable
  }
  Node(NodeType type) : m_nodeType(type) {}
  NodeType m_nodeType;
};

class ConstantNode {
  ConstantNode() : Node(Constant) {}
};
class VariableNode {
  VariableNode() : Node(Variable) {}
};

int calculate(Node* node) {
  switch (node->m_nodeType) {
    case Constant:
      //...
    case Variable:
      //...
  }
}
```

I know the enum version would require dynamic casting, but overall that seems preferable to have to repeat a lot of the same code, and it means it would allow for templates nodes eg (`BinOpNode<std::plus>`).

Alternatively is there some way of improving the visitor pattern in C++, so that it doesn't need all this repetition?

(Typed the code directly into stackoverflow, sorry for any mistakes but it's based on real code)

EDIT: for BinOpNode:

```
template<class T>
class BinOpNode {
  T m_op = T();
  BinOpNode() : Node(BinOp) {}
};

//in calculate:
case BinOpNode:
  BinOpNode* n = dynamic_cast<BinOpNode*>(node);
  return n->m_op(calculate(n->m_left), calculate(n->m_right));
```

Comment: It doesn't seem easier at all. The amount of repetition is the same (case labels vs virtual functions). You also didn't explain how you plan to process templates. `case BinOp:` now what?

Comment: There is less repetition because it removes the need for all the Accept functions. There will be constructors for the nodes in either situation.

Comment: Adding new visitor doesn't require repetition. and avoid to forget a type contrary to switch/enum case.

Comment: "removes the need for all the Accept functions" CRTP is your friend. Also look up "acyclic visitor".

Comment: I did try CRTP, but there was some problem, I can't remember right now. I will try again though.

Comment: @n.m. I have added code to show BinOpNode

Comment: There is no m_op in Node. There may be one in BinOpNode, how do you get to it?

Comment: @n.m. using dynamic cast?

Comment: If you are already using `dynamic_cast` I second what **n.m** said. Look up the "Acyclic Visitor" pattern in C++.

Comment: Is this what is meant by acyclic visitor? http://www.artima.com/cppsource/cooperative_visitor.html Because the whole tags, vtable, macros thing looks awful.

Comment: Dymamic cast to what type? Compilable code speaks louder than words.

Comment: @n.m. I added it to the question, I thought I added it already tbh

Comment: No, this is some variation I'm not familiar with. It seems to be built on a unique tag per class (which is exactly what your type enum is). For the original acyclic visitor search a paper by Robert C Martin.

Comment: I said compilable code :) There is no BinOpNode class. BinOpNode is a template. `BinOpNode<std::plus>` is probably a class.

Comment: @n.m. ah yeah, sorry.

Comment: I've decided that this is all too complicated for simply wanting to calculate the value of an expression tree, and I'll just add calculate methods to each node, giving much simpler code. It just seems like C++ is not suited to the visitor pattern (well at least a vaguely simple implementation of it)

Comment: @Jonathan. there is no vaguely simple implementation of it. The visitor pattern can quickly turn into an anti-pattern in any language. The GoF mentioned it as their least favorite one.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I can't remember which language exactly (I think it was Java), but at uni I had to implement it and didn't have to jump through a billion hoops and force the language to do this.

Comment: @Jonathan. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) doesn't look any less cyclic & tedious (from a design standpoint) than the C++ example on the page.

Comment: You don't really need `dynamic_cast`. Inside a switch, you've already checked what is the object type, so you can use `static_cast`. Use dynamic cast only when you are prepared for the cast to fail.

Comment: There is one other reason why visitor is better than a huge enum (which you need to repeat every time, every time you write a calculate function, by the way - and in some cases some values of the enum may not be valid, in some functions, in general) and that is the fact that you may forget to add a particular case to the enum, or alternatively you are going to copy and paste blocks of code which are difficult to keep in sync if any update is made to any of them, especially if the logic is not uniform between every place it is used. I perhaps haven't explained this well but the enum is not

Comment: preferable because you must add logic which may not be relevant to all the functions in which the switch statement occurs. It generally doesn't make sense to write sections of code which themselves include redundant or irrelevant sections of logic, which the enum method forces you to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the repetition by using templates:

```
// Classes implementing the mechanism

class Node {
  virtual void Accept(Visitor *visitor) = 0;
};

template<typename NodeType> class ConcreteNode
{
  virtual void Accept(Visitor* visitor)
  {
    visits<NodeType>* v = visitor;
    v->visit((NodeType*)this);
  }
};

template<typename NodeType> class visits
{
  virtual void visit(NodeType* node) = 0;
};

// The actual visitors/visited classes

class Visitor:
  visits<ConstantNode>,
  visits<VariableNode>
{
};

class ConstantNode : ConcreteNode<ConstantNote> {};
class VariableNode : ConcreteNode<VariableNode> {};

class CalculateVisitor : Visitor {
  virtual void visit(ConstantNode *node) { /* code */ }
  virtual void visit(VariableNode *node) { /* code */ }
};
```

Note that your template node code will *not* work, as the following line cannot work:

```
BinOpNode* n = dynamic_cast<BinOpNode*>(node);
```

`BinOpNode` you define as a template, and you cannot have a pointer to a template, only a pointer to a class. You might, for example, have a pointer to a *specific* class generated from `BinOpNode`, like

```
BinOpNode<int>* n = dynamic_cast<BinOpNode<int>*>(node);
```

but that is perfectly handled by the visitor pattern as well; with the template code above:

```
class Visitor:
  public visits<BinOpNode<int> >,
  public visits<BinOpNode<double> >,
  ...
{
};

template<typename T> class BinOpNode:
  public ConcreteNode<BinOpNode<T> >
{
  ...
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this is an improvement. You now have multiple inheritance where before you didn't need to have this. Unless I misunderstand this seems like a case of "it's debatable as to whether this is actually an improvement rather than making the situation vastly more complex when it didn't need to be". What is the advantage of this?